# Regular expression to remove time from time and date

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove time out of a scraped date and time field so i can sort the data by date. Here is a sample of what the data looks like:

```
12/21/19, 3:02 PM
```

I am trying to use a regular expression to replace the ", X:XXPM" with nothing and just leave the date but I cannot figure out how to do it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a regular expression it is fairly simple, you could just do

```
let data = "12/21/19, 3:02 PM"
let newData = data.split(",")[0]
```

If you *wish* to use a regular expression this would work, but its less readable.

```
let data = "12/21/19, 3:02 PM"
let newData = data.replace(/,.+/, "");
```

Comment: This is better than my answer. It's cleaner.

Comment: There's also `data.match(/(\d\d\/){2}\d\d/)` or `data.match(/^[^,]+/)` for the regex option (depending on format).

Comment: @ggorlen that's definitely better than what I did. Since the answer I put about it was all about removal I was just solely thinking about removal not matching.

Comment: @herohamp how would it be If the date doesn't have a comma ","?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need regular expression here, just a little substring.

```js
const dateAndTime = '12/21/19, 3:02 PM';

const dateOnly = dateAndTime.substring(0, dateAndTime.indexOf(','));

console.log(dateOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date can appear anywhere in a text, you could use this `replace`:

```js
let text = "On a dull day, 12/21/19, 3:02 PM, I was strawling along the beach";

text = text.replace(/\b((?:\d\d\/){2}\d\d)\W+\d\d?:\d\d\s[AP]M\b/g, "$1");

console.log(text);
```